# The Hardy–Littlewood maximal function is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue-integrable. We define the Hardy–Littlewood [maximal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) $Mf: \mathbb R^n \to [0, \infty]$ by

$$
M f(x) :=\sup _{r>0} \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} |f(t)| \mathrm d t
$$
where $B(x, r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, and $|E|$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $E \subset \mathbb R^n$.

> **Theorem:** $Mf$ is Borel measurable.

I'm trying to adapt the strategy in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3790560/368425) thread to higher dimension. Could you have a check on my attempt?

**Proof:** Let
$$
g_r (x) := \frac{1}{|B(x, r)|} \quad \text{and} \quad h_r(x) := \int_{B(x, r)} |f(t)| \mathrm d t \quad \forall r>0, \forall x \in \mathbb R^n.
$$

Because Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant, we get $g_r (x) = g_r (y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$. This means $g_r$ is constant. Let's prove that $h_r$ is continuous. Let $x, x_n \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $x_n \to x$. Because the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of a sphere is $0$, we have $1_{B(x_n, r)} \to 1_{B(x, r)}$ a.e. It follows that
$$
1_{B(x_n, r)} |f| \to 1_{B(x, r)} |f| \quad \text{a.e.}
$$

By dominated convergence theorem, we get $h_r (x_n) \to h_r (x)$ and thus $(g_rh_r) (x_n) \to (g_rh_r) (x)$. It follows that $g_rh_r$ is measurable. The supremum of a collection of measurable functions is measurable, so
$$
Mf = \sup_{r>0} g_rh_r
$$
is measurable.

Comment: Its almost correct. At the end, you have to say that the supremum of countably many measurable functions is measurable. The supremum can be taken over all positive rational numbers since $g_r(x)$ and $h_r(x)$ continuously depend on $r$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I actually missed that important subtlety. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little refinement of your sketch of proof.

A function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called *locally integrable*, denoted $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d,\lambda_d)$,  if $f\mathbb{1}_E\in\mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R}^d,\lambda_d)$ for all bounded measurable set $E$.

***Claim:***  For such function $f$ and fixed $r>0$, the map $$M_rf:x\mapsto \frac{1}{\lambda(B(x;r))}\int_{B(x;r)}f\,d\lambda=\frac{1}{\omega_n r^n}\int_{B(x;r)}f\,d\lambda$$
is continuous and hence measurable.

Indeed, for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ we have $f\mathbb{1}_{B(x;2r)}\in L^1$. Since $\|\mathbb{1}_{B(y;r)}-\mathbb{1}_{B(x;r)}\|_1\xrightarrow{y\rightarrow x}0$, the conclsion follows from
\begin{align*}
    \Big|\int_{B(y;r)}f\,d\lambda-\int_{B(x;r)}f\,d\lambda\Big|\leq \int_{B(x;r)\triangle B(y;r)}|f\mathbb{1}_{B(x;2r)}|\,d\lambda.
  \end{align*}
for $|x-y|<r$. Continuity follows from the following basic result:

> $f\in L_1(\mu)$ then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies that $\int_A|f|\,d\mu<\varepsilon$.

It follows that the map
$x\mapsto\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x;r))}\int_{B(x;r)}\,d\lambda=\sup_{r>0}M_rf(x)$ is lower semicontinuous and so, measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another elementary approach $:$

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb R,$ consider the set $A_{\alpha} : = \left \{x \in \mathbb R^n\ |\ Mf(x) \gt \alpha \right \}.$ We claim that $A_{\alpha}$ is open and hence Borel measurable in particular.

Take $x \in A_{\alpha}$ arbitrarily. Then $M f(x) \gt \alpha$ i.e.

$$\sup\limits_{r \gt 0} \frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x,r) \right \rvert} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(t)|\ dt > \alpha.$$ So by the property of supremum there exists $r_0 \gt 0$ such that $$\frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x,r_0) \right \rvert} \int_{B(x,r_0)} |f(t)|\ dt > \alpha.$$ Choose $r' \gt r \gt 0$ such that $$\tag{*}\frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x,r') \right \rvert} \int_{B(x,r_0)} |f(t)|\ dt > \alpha.$$ This is possible by the virtue of intermediate value theorem as the function $x \mapsto \frac {1} {x^n}$  is continuous and decreasing on $(0, \infty)$ and since $$\left \lvert B(y,s) \right \rvert = \left \lvert B(0,s) \right \rvert = c_n s^n$$ for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $s \gt 0$ (by the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure),  where $c_n = \left \lvert B(0,1) \right \rvert$ is an absolute constant (independent of $y$ and $s$). Now let $x' \in B(x,r' - r_0)$ so that $\|x' - x\| \lt r' - r_0.$

**Claim** $:$ $B(x,r_0) \subseteq B(x',r').$

Indeed if $y \in B(x,r_0)$ then $\|y - x\| \lt r_0.$ Hence it follows that $$\|y - x'\| \leq \|y - x\| + \|x - x'\| \lt r_0 + (r' - r_0) = r'$$ i.e. $y \in B(x',r'),$ as claimed. So we have by $(*)$ $$\alpha \lt \frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x,r') \right \rvert} \int_{B(x,r_0)} |f(t)|\ dt \leq \frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x',r') \right \rvert} \int_{B(x',r')} |f(t)|\ dt$$ Here $\left \lvert B(x,r') \right \rvert = \left \lvert B(x',r') \right \rvert,$ by the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure. This shows that $$\sup\limits_{r \gt 0} \frac {1} {\left \lvert B(x',r) \right \rvert} \int_{B(x',r)} |f(t)|\ dt \gt \alpha$$ i.e. $M f(x') \gt \alpha$ and hence $x' \in A_{\alpha}.$ So it follows that $B(x,r' - r_0) \subseteq A_{\alpha},$ which shows that $A_{\alpha}$ is an open set. $\blacksquare$